# ReactJS: programmatically change component tag with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am making a conditional component that returns `<a>` if *href* is defined and returns `<div>` if not. I am doing this way:

```
const Label = ({children, ...other}) => {
    let component;
    if (other.href)
        component =
            <a {...other}>
                { children }
            </a>
    else
        component =
            <div {...other}>
                { children }
            </div>

    return component;
}

export default Label
```

There is any way to make this component by only changing the tag name? I know that if I use the manual way of creating compontents (`React.createElement`) I can do this by changing the first argument passed, for it's a string. But with JSX it's a little different. I though something like

```
let component =
    <{tag} {...other}>
        { children }
    </{tag}>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
const Label = ({children, ...other}) => {
  let component;

  if (other.href) {
    component = <a {...other}>{ children }</a>;
  } else if (other.tag) {
    const Tag = other.tag;
    component = <Tag {...other}>{ children }</Tag>;
  } else {
    component = <div {...other}>{ children }</div>;
  }
  return component;
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Label href="#">Hello World</Label>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );

 ReactDOM.render(
    <Label>Not a Link</Label>,
  document.getElementById('rootTwo')
 );


 ReactDOM.render(
    <Label tag="p">Paragraph</Label>,
  document.getElementById('rootThree')
 );
```

**Working demo:**, https://jsfiddle.net/tgm4htac/

Comment: You can try the Babel repl `const Tag = 'p';`
`<Tag >Hello</Tag>;` transpiles to this `var Tag = 'p';`
`React.createElement( Tag, null, 'Hello' );` I think you just need the jsx tag as a variable, not sure if it needs to be _capitalized_

Comment: It's valuable to note that Tag **must** be capitalized, because React interpeter lowercased as html tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass to `<>` values like `component.tag` and `JSX transpiler` can create dynamic tags.

```
const Label = ({children, tag, ...other}) => {
  const component = { tag: tag };

  return (<component.tag {...other}>
    { children }
  </component.tag>);
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/j6hgb7mL/)

or

```
const Label = ({children, tag, ...other}) => {
  const Component = tag;

  return (<Component {...other}>
    { children }
  </Component>);
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/8we7k4dL/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Specifically the second example in my case.